# Custom partition of kafka topics using Spring Boot

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-kafka

Is there a way to create partition key based on hash calculated on an attribute of payload using Spring Boot. There is an interface called `Partition` in apache-kafka, but not sure how to allocate the messages into different partitions using Spring boot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See [the kafka documentation](https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/).

Set the `partitioner.class` producer property to your class name.

> `partitioner.class`
>
> Partitioner class that implements the `org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.Partitioner interface`.
>
> default:`org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.DefaultPartitioner`